# Nginx directive limit_conn not working

Tags: nginx

I can't get the nginx limit_conn directive to work properly.

I have the following nginx configuraton:

```
http {
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=per_ip:10m;
    proxy_cache_path /var/nginx/cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=caching:10m max_size=10g inactive=525600m use_temp_path=off;
    server {
        listen 80;
        expires -1;
        limit_conn per_ip 1;
        limit_conn_status 403;
        location ~ / {
            proxy_pass http://upstream;
            proxy_cache caching;
        }
    }
}
```

If I query the server with the following python script I expect that the second request should return a 403 response.

```
import httplib

headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

conn1 = httplib.HTTPConnection('nginx-server')
conn1.request('GET', '/path/to/resource', '', headers)
res1 = conn1.getresponse()
print(res1.status)

conn2 = httplib.HTTPConnection('nginx-server')
conn2.request('GET', '/path/to/resource', '', headers)
res2 = conn2.getresponse()
# Should print 403 but most often it prints 200
print(res2.status)

conn1.close()
conn2.close()
```

The response status code is not consistent for the second request. Sometimes a 200 is returned and sometimes a 403 is returned.

Perhaps I misunderstand the meaning of the limit_conn directive, right now I expect the second request to always return 403.

nginx version: nginx/1.11.9

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is working. The reason why I think you sometimes getting 200 and sometimes getting 403 is that sometimes by the time your second request runs, the first one has already finished, leaving the nginx server has no connection again.

One thing I come up with is to make the request a long request by sleeping. In the case of nginx, you can use `echo_sleep` to sleep certain seconds.

```
location ~ / {
    echo_sleep 1.234; 
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
    proxy_cache caching;
}
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: The first connection is not closed when the second connection is issuing its request. This, I am sure of (checked with wireshark). It could be that a connection only counts when performing actual work but I can't find this documented anywhere. But what is the purpose of this directive then? A DDOS attack can then fill the server with useless connections.